# Joomla admin errors on google app engine php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, joomla

Trying to get joomla working locally and ran into an issue with the Administror page. I have this error,

home page of site works - www.my-site.index.php
but with admin I find the following error - www.my-site/administrator.index.php

```
Warning: require(/Users/RichardClark/Sites/demo-test2/joomla/administrator): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php on line 115

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Users/RichardClark/Sites/demo-test2/joomla/administrator' (include_path='/Users/RichardClark/Sites/demo-test2:/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/php/sdk') in /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php on line 115
```

I get the impressions joomla and google app engine aren't very compatible. I am really struggling to debug this. My app.yaml file is as follows;

```
application: fit-rig-517
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /joomla/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: joomla/\1
  upload: joomla/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  application_readable: true

## Admin  
- url: /administrator(.+)
  script: joomla/administrator\1

## Asset folders
- url: /media
  static_dir: joomla/media
  application_readable: true
  mime_type: text/html

- url: /images
  static_dir: joomla/images
  application_readable: true

## Template folders
- url: /templates
  static_dir: joomla/templates
  application_readable: true
  mime_type: application/(htm$|html$|css$|js$)

- url: /administrator/templates
  static_dir: joomla/administrator/templates
  application_readable: true
  mime_type: text/html

## SEO robots
- url: /robots.txt
  script: joomla/robots.txt 

## Site access
- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: joomla/index.php
```

thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, you're attempting to deploy the cms right?

Comment: this is just local. The aim is to deploy however i want to make sure all works locally and this is still a problem. I edited the question above too to clarify the url which doesn't work.

Comment: I haven't ever used Google app engine, but I can tell you that there is no file with the name it is looking for, that's a folder name. Maybe you should add the index.php?

Answer (score 0):

App Engine does not have the concept of a default script (e.g. index.php) for directory access. Instead, it relies on the following rule in your app.yaml to locate the php script.

```
## Admin  
- url: /administrator(.+)
  script: joomla/administrator\1
```

Use /administrator/index.php to access your admin page instead.